# Question about convergence in $L^2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Assume we have a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}_{n\geq 0}\subset L^2([0,1])$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^2([0,1])$, i.e.
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 |f_n(x)-f(x)|^2dx =0.$$

Is it then true that for every continuous function $g$ we have
$$g(f_n) \rightarrow g(f)$$
in $L^2([0,1])$? That is
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 |g(f_n(x))-g(f(x))|^2 dx =0?$$

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: $g(f)=g\circ f$ ?

Comment: Yes. I see it clearly for Lipschitz continuous functions. I have the feeling it also holds for general continuous functions...

Comment: In that case, perhaps you can appropriately approximate $g$ by Lipschitz continuous $g_n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $g(x) = x^2$. Consider $f_n \to 0$ in $L^2$. If your property was true, it would means that $f_n \to 0$ in $L^4$

Now just take

$$f_n(x) = x^{-\frac{1}{4}} \times\mathbb{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}(x)$$

$f_n \to 0$ in $L^2$, but $f_n$ is not in $L^4$

Hence you have both

$$\int_0^1 [f_n(x)- 0|^2 dx = \int_0^{\frac{1}{n}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} dx = 2\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}\to 0$$

$$\int_0^1 |(f_n(x))^2- 0^2|^2 dx = \int_0^{\frac{1}{n}} \frac{1}{x} dx = +\infty$$

Comment: But $x^2$ is Lipschitz in $[0,1]$ so $|g(f_n(x))-g(f(x))| \leq \sup_{z\in [0,1]} \{|2z|\} |f_n(x)-f(x)|$ and hence squaring and integrating we actually get $\int_0^1 |g(f_n(x))-g(f(x))|^2 dx \rightarrow 0$.. where am I wrong?

Comment: Where you're wrong is that $f_n$ is **not** at value in $[0,1]$. You need to be Lipschitz on the whole range of $f_n$ for your property to hold. Here the range of $f_n$ is $\mathbb{R}^+$, and $x^2$ is not Lipschitz on $\mathbb{R}^+$

Comment: Aha.. so the statement would then hold for $g$ functions that are Lipschitz on the range of $f$ or globally Lipschitz on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Not on the range of $f$, as the range of the $f_n$ can be greater than the range of $f$ (in my exemple it's the case). But if you're lipschitz on $\mathbb{R}$ or on $\limsup \text{range}(f_n)$, yes, that's right

Comment: I see, thanks a lot! then a last quick question, if one has $\int_0^1 g(f(x))dx = \int_0^1 g(h(x))dx$ for all globally Lipschitz functions $g$ can we say that $f=h$ a.e.? this is why I was looking at this :)