# Question about convergence in $L^2$ (revisited)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Yesterday I asked the folowing question:

[Question about convergence in $L^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1235815/question-about-convergence-in-l2)

which was answered negatively with a counterexample. Here, I wonder if one can find the right set to look at:

Assume we have a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}_{n\geq 0}\subset L^2([0,1])$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^2([0,1])$, i.e.
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 |f_n(x)-f(x)|^2dx =0.$$

Is it then true that for every continuous and **bounded** function $g$ we have
$$g(f_n) \rightarrow g(f)$$
in $L^2([0,1])$? That is
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 |g(f_n(x))-g(f(x))|^2 dx =0?$$

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: You should just use the Dominated Convergence Theorem. (The sequence of integrands has an integrable majorant)

Comment: So you mean $|g(f_n(x))-g(f(x))|^2 \leq 4\|g\|_{\infty}^2$ which is integrable in $[0,1]$ and hence $\lim_n \int_0^1 |g(f_n(x))-g(f(x))|^2 dx = \int_0^1   \lim_n |g(f_n(x))-g(f(x))|^2 dx$? But then I need $\lim_n |g(f_n(x))-g(f(x))|^2 =0$ for every $x$. Since $|\cdot|^2$ and $g$ are continuous I need pointwise convergence of $f_n$ right? Where am I wrong?

Comment: You don't need the limit to be zero for every x: If it is zero for almost every x, the integral is still zero.

Comment: Do you need just convergence almost everywhere.

Comment: Yes of course, almost for every, my mistake, thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemytskii_operator